# Long-run vectors, rates, and fractions

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question regarding Markov chains. All help would be appreciated, alongside comments.

The question is: suppose there are 3 types of workers: (1) unemployed; (2) Working for Firm A; (3) Working for Firm B.

If a worker is unemployed

- 0.20 chance they will remain unemployed
- 0.40 chance they will move to Firm A in the next period
- 0.40 chance they will move to Firm B in the next period

If the Worker is Employed for either Firm A or B, the probabilities are:

- 0.70 chance they will stay in the same firm for the next period
- 0.25 they will switch firms in the next period
- 0.05 they will become unemployed in the next period.

Assume also that 20% of the workforce are unemployed, 50% work for Firm A, and 30% for Firm B.

Is it possible to compute the long-run vector of probabilities? And show the long-run rate of unemployment? And the fraction of persons working for firm A and B in the long-run?

Any help/feedback would be massively appreciated.

Best,

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Because of the symmetry between the two firms, you can just focus on the fraction unemployed.  Call it $u$.  Then $\frac 12(1-u)$ work for each firm.  At stability, we must have the the fraction unemployed the same before and after a step.  If we start with $u$ unemployed after a step we have $0.2u+0.05(1-u)$ unemployed so
$$u=0.2u+0.05(1-u)\\
0.85u=0.05\\
u=\frac {0.05}{0.85}=\frac 1{17}$$
and $\frac 8{17}$ work for each firm

You can make a spreadsheet with columns for $U,A,B$ and each row being one more step.  Copy down makes it easy.  Convergence is rapid.  I got to nine places in $30$ steps.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_n = 1,2$ and $3$ corresponding to "unemployed," "working for firm A," and "working for firm B," respectively. Then $\{X_n:n=0,1,2,\ldots\}$ is a Markov chain with transition matrix
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac15&\frac25&\frac25\\\frac1{20}&\frac7{10}&\frac14\\\frac1{20}&\frac14&\frac7{10}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and initial distribution $\alpha = \begin{pmatrix} \frac15&\frac12&\frac3{10}\end{pmatrix}$. Here $\alpha$ is the distribution of $X_0$ and the $(i,j)^{\mathrm{th}}$ entry of $P$ is $\mathbb P(X_{n+1}=j\mid X_n=i)$. Since $\{X_n\}$ has finitely many states and $P$ is irreducible and aperiodic, $\{X_n\}$ has a unique stationary distribution $\pi$ satisfying $\pi P=\pi$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P(X_n=j\mid X_0=i)=\pi_j$ (independent of $X_0$). Since $P$ is a stochastic matrix (the rows each sum to one), the system $\pi P = \pi$ is linearly dependent, but because $\pi$ is a probability distribution, we also have the equation $\sum_{i=1}^3 \pi_i = 1$. So we take two equations from $\pi P = \pi$ together with the prior equation to form the system of equations:
\begin{align}
\pi_1 &= \frac15\pi_1 + \frac1{20}\pi_2 + \frac1{20}\pi_3\\
\pi_2 &= \frac25\pi_1 + \frac7{10}\pi_2 + \frac14\pi_3\\
\pi_1 + \pi_2 + \pi_3 &= 1.
\end{align}
Solving this system yields
$$
\pi_1 = \frac1{17},\quad\pi_2 = \frac8{17},\quad\pi_3 = \frac8{17}.
$$

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your time and contributions! Genuinely appreciated